# 0x8000000a - JavaScript runtime error: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been experiencing the error (in the title) and have been trying to find an answer. The best one so far is [AJAX Error: The data necessary to complete this operation is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038305/ajax-error-the-data-necessary-to-complete-this-operation-is-unavailable).

However, in that case, the OP was specifically using jQuery/Ajax, but I am using the AjaxControlToolkit and I am not sure how to implement the answer and was hoping someone may be able to help.

FYI: In most of the questions on the subject all say that the problem does not exist in Chrome/Firefox etc. (and it does when I try), but I am using IE (as its company policy) and am running IE 10 on Windows 8, using Visual Studio 2013

EDIT - Added code.

Very simple, but gives the error.

> Webform1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="HotTransferBags.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 4" Value="4" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 5" Value="5" />
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Code Behind - Webform1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HotTransferBags
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error reported in Visual Studio...

As this is a simple form, only one error is reported, but my full application lists about 20 of them

[image: JavaScript Error in Visual Studio Error List Window]

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Added a simple extract @MarcoCI